What is the average number of moves in a chess game where white wins? And the average number of moves where black wins?
I would imagine that the average number of moves in a chess game where white wins would be less than the average number of moves where black wins. And that is because black has first to neutralize white's opening advantage. Or put another way, in a game where black prevails, white will have to commit an extra bad move versus one where white prevails. But I don't have numbers. Might someone be able to shed some light on this?

I used my SCID "Example" database (which has about 127K games, mostly consisting of GM games from 2000-2016) and ran the Opening Report on the initial position to get game stats.
According to the report, the average length of games where White wins was 46, while the average length of games where Black wins was 47. The average length of a drawn game was 39. Since it does not give decimals, we cannot consider the difference between White and Black wins to be significant from this.
